# How to import a String from a a different Class

Tags: java, string

I have been trying to import a String from the `classA` to the `classB` by using constructor, but I don't get to use the String in the `classB`, why is that so?. The code:

**class A:**

```
class classA{
        String A="THIS IS THE STRING";
        String B="TEXTL: ";
        public classA(){
        this.A=B+A;
        }   
        }
```

**class B:**

```
class classB extends classA{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        classA newclassA=new classA();
        String Z=A;                           //WHY A IS NOT RECOGNIZED, WHAT DO I NEED TO DO?
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should start by learning Java.

Comment: Please tell me, my code is actually longer, is just that this is the part where I have the problem.

Comment: This is a very basic java concept that you can not access non-static variable/method from static method (in your case main method is static).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the scope of your variables. You can find more informatnion [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Currently the variables stored in class A have package-private scope. There are really two ways to do what you are describing.

The better solution would be to provide a getter method within classA:

```
public String getA(){
   return this.A;
}
```

This will access the A variable within the instance of the classA class. You can then change your main() to the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    classA newclassA=new classA();
    String Z= newclassA.getA(); // Z = "TextL: THIS IS THE STRING";
}
```

Another option is to change the scope to protected to allow subclasses to access the variable field directly. i.e.

```
class classA{
    protected String A="THIS IS THE STRING";
    private String B="TEXTL: ";

    public classA(){
        this.A=B+A;
    }   
}
```

and

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    classA newclassA=new classA();
    String Z= newclassA.A; // Z = "TextL: THIS IS THE STRING";
    // this allows you to access fields as if you were in the actual classA class.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps.

```
public class stringName {

        public String getString(String s){

            s =" String in stringName class";
            return s;
        }

}


public class OutputString {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String s = " ";
        stringName sN = new stringName();

        System.out.println(sN.getString(s) + " The string in the OutputString Class");
    }
}
```